# Import Data From csv Into Postgresql WITHOUT COPY

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, csv

I am writing a function for a python environment which needs to import data from a csv file into an existing table. The scope in which the function can execute does not allow for a db SUPERUSER to run the function and so the COPY function is out of the question.

What other options are efficient?

The files range from 100,000 to 1,000,000 rows.

This question has also been posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154670/7788)

Comment: x-posted http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154670/7788

Comment: This question has also been posted [here][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [psycopg2's `COPY ... FROM STDIN` support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from).

Comment: I will look into that immediately. Thanks a lot!

Comment: x-posted. I am not familiar with this term. Is this relating to my posting the exact same question on multiple forums?

Comment: Right. "cross-post". It helps people avoid wasting time answering it in multiple places because they don't know it's answered elsewhere. It also helps other people looking at the same question later find an answer. I find it quite rude to post many places like that without cross-referencing them, it shows disrespect for others' time and for the quality of the knowledge base. If you posted other places please edit your question to link to appropriate forums, list archives, etc.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The function requests a buffer size parameter. How do you determine an appropriate buffer size?

Comment: Its not a required parameter. I will ignore it